Character encoding issue solution
While reading the data from on premises SQL server the column has collation setting in SQL server .so while reading data using AWS glue dynamic it was coming with weird value like question may I know how to properly encode it while reading from SQL server
How to to encode while reading from SQL server

Please, post one or more examples of the expected strings, and the strings you are obtaining. Also, try to create a minimal reproducible code example with the code for your connection, SQL cursos intantiation if any, and SQL query and execution. (the lines of code for each of these actions, just preserving your host names/IDs/users and passwords, of course).  Also, in which OS are you executing the code, and how you are outputing it (a web page? the terminal? A text file? A jupyter cell? )

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
